# Plugging MacBook Pro's display assembly onto MacBook Air Logic Board

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

As a temporary replacement, can I plug a MacBook Pro 13" mid 2009's display assembly onto my 13" mid 2011 MacBook Air's logic board?

It is ok if it cannot close, or is not transportable. All I need is to be able to troubleshoot my MacBook Air.

I am wondering :

1. whether it will work
2. whether it can damage either the display or the laptop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to people on iFixit, NO.

It seems that the pinouts of the connectors on Macbook Pros and Macbook Airs are different, and thus while it is physically possible to plug a Macbook Pro screen on a Macbook Air, doing so would cause very serious damage, to the motherboard and/or the screen itself.

Answer (score 3):

**Technically speaking, it *should* work.**

Even though (according to Everymac.com), the [2009 MBP display](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-2-duo-2.26-aluminum-13-mid-2009-sd-firewire-800-unibody-specs.html) has a resolution of 1280x800 and the 2011 MacBook Air has a display of 1400x900 it is capable of a resolution of 1280x800.

[MacBook Air](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook-air/specs/macbook-air-core-i5-1.7-13-mid-2011-specs.html):

[image]

How you are implementing it, however, will be th how you make the connection.  With a little research on iFixit.com, you can see that the LVDS connecorts for the MacBook Pro and the MacBook Air are on opposite sides of the logic board

[image]
[image]

(Left Image is MacBook Pro and right image is MacBook Air)

So, even though closing and mobility is not a big concern, you would have to at least turn the display the "wrong way round" to just make the connection.

If you do attempt this, I highly advise you to isolate the logic board from any potential shorts by putting a silicone or plastic barrier (think place mat) over the logic board.

Comment: Actually I got information from people on iFixit that the pinouts are different between macbook pros and macbook airs, and thus that plugging a Macbook pro screen on a Macbook air could cause very serious damage